# cast helper for overloaded member function pointer

Tags: c++, casting, pointer-to-member

I want to have a "nicer" cast operation for a pointer to method.

Given is a class with overloaded member functions and a template which eats every kind of member pointers and objects and simply call them.

```
class A
{
    public:
        void Do( int i ) { std::cout << "Hallo with int " << i << std::endl;}
        void Do( float f ) { std::cout << "and with float " << f << std::endl;}
        void Do( std::string s ) { std::cout << "also with string " << s << std::endl;}
};

    template <typename OBJECT, typename METHOD, typename ... PARMS>
void Call( OBJECT& obj, METHOD m, PARMS ... parms)
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;

    (obj.*m)(parms...);
}
```

Now, if I want to use the `Call` template, I have to manually cast the pointer to get the correct version of overloaded functions like:

```
   Call( a, static_cast< void(A::*)(int)>( &A::Do ), 1);
   Call( a, static_cast< void(A::*)(float)>( &A::Do ), 8.88);
   Call( a, static_cast< void(A::*)(std::string)>( &A::Do ), "Willi");
```

So I like to make the cast a bit easier to read and got this helper class:

```
template <typename > class Cast;

template < typename RET, typename ... ARGS >
class Cast< RET(ARGS...)>
{
    public:
        template < typename OBJ >
            static auto From( RET(OBJ::*ptr)(ARGS...))-> RET(OBJ::*)(ARGS...)
            {
                return ptr;
            }
};
```

and can use it as:

```
    Call( a, Cast<void(int)>::From( &A::Do ), 100);
    Call( a, Cast<void(float)>::From( &A::Do ), 4.46);
    Call( a, Cast<void(std::string)>::From( &A::Do ),"Check it");
```

Q:
Is it possible to make my class `Cast` a template function to get the syntax for the cast call a bit easier? I want something which can be called like this:

```
Call( a, Cast<void(std::string)>(  &A::Do ), "Yeeeaaa!");
```

But I can't find a way to write a template function this way because any kind of specialisation I wrote was not allowed.

Any kind of c++ is allowed. If C++17 gives a new way, let me know!

Why I can't use the parameters for a lambda inside the call function:

My real code needs only to register the pointers but do not call the pointers direct. So the cast function must also work with:

```
Register( a, Cast<void(int)>::From( &A::Do ));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to separate out arguments and result type only to join them again. Just declare a member pointer to the function type:

```
template <typename F, typename C>
auto Cast(F (C::*ptr)) {
    return ptr;    
}
```

Your desired syntax works:

```
Call(a, Cast<void(std::string)>(&A::Do), "Yeeeaaa!");
```

Comment: I never seen such a syntax before! It works perfect but can you please explain what `Cast(F (C::*ptr))` does? I can't replace with: `Cast( void(int) C::*)` if F is not a template parameter. So I am confused about that syntactic form.

Comment: No, that's exactly what's going on. C++ just doesn't let you directly write a composite type in there, like you can't declare an array with `int[42] a;`, yet you can do `using A = int[42]; A a;` Same here: `using F = void(int); auto Cast(F C::*){}` does what you expect.

Comment: @Klaus, this is not a pointer to function! This is a generic pointer to member, any member it is. So, when called like this, you give it a pointer to member having type `void(std::string)`. Again - pay attention, there are no second set of parenthethis. May be it will be more clear if written without parenthesis at all: `auto Cast(F C::*ptr)` - same result.

Comment: @SergeyA: Thanks. I never saw before that the type of a function can be written as `retval(parms...) before. Can you maybe point me to a document where this kind of syntax is used/explained a bit more. Also the `using A = int[42]; A a;` is quite crazy for me. This open a new door in c++ syntax. Thanks!

Comment: @Klaus, not sure what you mean by 'never saw'. This is exactly what you have in the original example!

Comment: @SergeyA: I should better write "I did not understand..." that `ret(parms...)`  is a type. Exactly a type of a function?! because it is not a pointer here.

Comment: @Klaus **I never saw before that the type of a function can be written as retval(parms...)**. Sure you did, you even used it in your question: `Call(a, Cast<void(int)>::From(&A::Do), 100); Call(a, Cast<void(float)>::From(&A::Do), 4.46); Call(a, Cast<void(std::string)>::From(&A::Do), "Check it");` Here `void(int)`, `void(float)` and `void(std::string)` are such function types.

Comment: @Klaus, yes! But you used that in your example. What do you think it was in your original code?

Comment: @SergeyA: You are right with your observation, yes, I used that syntax. But now I start to understand it.;) Simply that...